# Check if a file exist in FTP with an automated bash script

Tags: bash, ftp

I want to automate a batch job that does the following:

1. check if my `file.txt` exists in a FTP server, I rename it to
   `file.trt`
2. check if my `file.txt` and `file.trt` exist, if so I send an email
3. I run another script
4. at the end I delete `file.trt`

Here's what I have done:

```
#!/bin/bash
host='ftp.xxxx.com'
USER='xxxx'
PASSWD='xxxx'

ftp -n -v $host << EOF
ascii
user $USER $PASSWD
prompt
mls /TEST/file.txt test.txt
quit
EOF

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] 
    then
        echo "The File file.txt Exists";
    else 
        echo "The File file.txt dons not Exist";
fi
```

Am confused and don't know how to do it, can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

I did this and it works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
host='ftp.xxxx.com'
USER='xxxx'
PASSWD='xxxx'

FTPFile1="/TEST/file.txt"
FTPFile2="/TEST/file.trt"


#search file.txt et file.trt on the ftp server
ftp -n -v $host << EOT
ascii
user $USER $PASSWD
prompt
mls $FTPFile1 $FTPFile2 test.txt
quit
EOT

# # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
# # test if file.txt et file.trt are present => send mail
# # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

if grep -inr '/TEST/file.txt' test.txt && grep -inr '/TEST/file.trt' test.txt
    then
        echo "" | mail -s "aaaaa] Error, aaaaa." mail@mail.fr -c mail@mail.fr 
        
    elif grep -inr '/TEST/file.txt' test.txt 
        then
        echo "The File file.trt does not Exist (no loading at the moment), rename file.txt to file.trt and start loading";

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#       
    # rename file.txt 
    #  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

ftp -n -v $host<< EOT
    user $USER $PASSWD
    get $FTPFile1 file.txt
    rename $FTPFile1 $FTPFile2 
    quit
EOT

    else
        echo " file.txt (file not yet ready). No action to do."     
fi

# ------------------------------------#     

    ftp -n -v $host << EOT
    user $USER $PASSWD
    get $FTPFile1 file.txt
    quit
EOT

    TRT_DATE=`cat file.txt | grep -Po "[0-9]{8}"`

        
        # run my_script.sh  
              ./my_script.sh -d $TRT_DATE
    
#delete file.txt et test.txt 
rm -f file.txt test.txt

# delete file.trt
ftp -n -v $host << EOT
    user $USER $PASSWD
    delete $FTPFile2 
    quit
EOT

exit 0
```